# Request URL: http://localhost:8000/user Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000 in django rest & react axios

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, axios, react-typescript

i am trying to do ultimate authantication in django and reactjs typescript and is giveng me error like 401 i have doing in 3wek to solve this can you help me please

""""""""""**django**""""""""

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.

class Users(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

class UserToken(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    token = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expired_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Reset(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import exceptions
from .Serializers import UserSerializers
from .models import Users, UserToken, Reset
from .authentication import create_access_token, create_refresh_token, JWTAuthentication, decode_refresh_token
import datetime, random, string
from django.core.mail import send_mail 



class RegisterAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        data = request.data

        if data['password'] != data['password_confirm']:
            raise exceptions.APIException('password do not match!')

        serializer = UserSerializers(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)

class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = Users.objects.filter(email=email).first()

        if user is None:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials ')

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials')

        access_token = create_access_token(user.id)
        
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(user.id)

        UserToken.objects.create(
            user_id = user.id,
            token = refresh_token,
            expired_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        )

        response = Response()

        response.set_cookie(key='refresh_token', value=refresh_token, httponly=True)
        response.data = {
            'token': access_token
        }

        return response


class UserAPIView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    
    def get(self, request):
        return Response(UserSerializers(request.Users).data)


class RefreshAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        refresh_token = request.COOKIES.get('refresh_token')
        id = decode_refresh_token(refresh_token)
        
        if not UserToken.objects.filter(
            user_id =id,
            token = refresh_token,
            expired_at__gt = datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
        ) .exists():
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('unathenticated')

        access_token = create_access_token(id)

        return Response({
            'token': access_token
        })

class LogoutAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        refresh_token = request.COOKIES.get('refresh_token')
        UserToken.objects.filter(token= refresh_token).delete()

        response = Response()
        response.delete_cookie(key='refresh_token')
        response.data = {
            'message': 'success'
        }
        return response

class ForgetAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        token = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))

        Reset.objects.create(
            email = email,
            token = token            
        )

        url = 'http//localhost:3000/reset/' + token

        send_mail(
            subject = 'Reset Your Password ',
            message = 'Click <a href="%s">Here</a> to reset your password!' % url,
            from_email = 'from@example.com',
            recipient_list = [email]
        )

        return Response({
            'message': 'success'
        })


class ResetAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data

        if data['password'] != data['password_confirm']:
            raise exceptions.APIException('password do not match!')
        
        reset_password = Reset.objects.filter(token=data['token']).first()

        if not reset_password:
            raise exceptions.APIException('Invalid Link!')
        
        user = Users.objects.filter(email=reset_password.email).first()


        if not user:
            raise exceptions.APIException('User not found')

        user.set_password(data['password'])
        user.save()

        return Response({
            'message': 'success'
        })
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**authentication.py**

```
import jwt, datetime, pytz
from django.utils.timezone import utc
from .models import Users
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication, get_authorization_header

class JWTAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
            auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()
            if auth and len(auth) == 2:
                token = auth[1].decode('utf-8')
                id = decode_access_token(token)

                user = Users.objects.get(pk=id)

                return (user, None)    
            
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('unAuthenticated')


def create_access_token(id):
    return jwt.encode({
        'user_id': id,
        'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),
        'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    }, 'access_secret', algorithm='HS256')


def decode_access_token(token):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, 'access_secret', algorithms='HS256')

        return payload['user_id']
    
    except:
          
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('unAuthenticated')


def create_refresh_token(id):
    return jwt.encode({
        'user_id': id,
        'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=7),
        'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) 
    }, 'refresh_secret', algorithm='HS256')


def decode_refresh_token(token):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, 'refresh_secret', algorithms='HS256')

        return payload['user_id']
    
    except:
        
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('unAuthenticated')
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**exception.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def status_code_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None and response.status_code == 403:
        response.status_code = 401
    
    return response
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**serializers.py**

```
from .models import Users
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class UserSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
        extra_kwaegs = {
            'password' : {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

"""""""""""""**Reactjs TypeScript**""""""""""""""""

**Home.tsx**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Home() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect( () => {
    (async () => {
      try{
        const response = await axios.get('user');
        const user = response.data;
        setMessage(`Hello ${user.first_name}`);

      }catch (e){
        setMessage('Your Are Not Authantication');
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='container mt-5 text-center text-white'>
      <h3>{message}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**Axios.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.interceptors.response.use(resp => resp, async error => {
    if(error.response.status === 401) {
        const response = await axios.post('refresh', {});


        if(response.status === 200){
            return axios(error.config)
        }
    }


    return error;
}) ;
```

Comment: I'm no JS/TS expert but, can you show us where you set the bearer token?

Comment: authentication.py

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the auth token from client side.

in your Axios.ts

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/';

const getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage = () => {
    let data = window.localStorage.getItem("USER_AUTH_DATA");
    if (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data) {
            const { access, refresh } = data;
            return access
        }
     }
    return null;
};

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage()}`;  // insert your access token here

axios.interceptors.response.use(resp => resp, async error => {
    if(error.response.status === 401) {
        const response = await axios.post('refresh', {});


        if(response.status === 200){
            return axios(error.config)
        }
    }


    return error;
}) ;
```

[EDIT] : In response to the first comment.
In your views.py class LoginAPIView, you already return the access token on successful login. You need to save that accesstoken in your frontend (local storage or Redux). Then in your Axios.ts you need to get that access token.
Bascially from backend you have implemented correctly, you need to implement it in your frontend side as well.For example if you are storing your access token in client side local storage.

[NOTE} At the time of successfull login, you need to save the access token in your client side local storage.

[NOTE-2] The above code is bare minimum to make your code working. For proper production use you may also like to make use of the refresh token.

Comment: wich AccessToken i put in my code can you explane me please